# changing a single line in a file

Tags: bash

I have a file with about 2000 lines.
What is the easiest way to change a particular line to something else.
say for example I want to change the 400th line from:   int cut_off = flow_max_-6;
to int cut_off = flow_max_-8;

I need to do this in the linux console

Comment: Chanditha - welcome to StackOverflow. Now you've used it a few times, you must be finding it useful. Reward those people who took the time to answer you questions. Go and mark the best answers with 'accepted' and upvote all which were particularly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by using `sed`:

```
sed -i '400s/6/8/' yourfile.c
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Vim](http://www.vim.org/).

But you may prefer:

```
sed -e '400,400s/6/8/' two_thousand_line_file.txt > new_two_thousand_line_file.txt
```

More generically:

```
sed -e '400,400s/[[:digit:]]{1,}/8/' two_thousand_line_file.txt > new_two_thousand_line_file.txt
```

Or:

```
sed -e '400,400s/\(int cut_off = flow_max_\).*\(;\)/\1some_other_number\2/' two_thousand_line_file.txt > new_two_thousand_line_file.txt
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that. But it only works if it is "flow_max_-6". the number has to be 6. How can i change it so that it will replace that line for any number?

So basically the first part " int cut_off = flow_max_" remains the same. I guess a regular expression is needed. Im just starting linux and im not that good with them.

Comment: That would require a regular expression. I've added a sample.

Comment: @Chanditha, the best thanks is up-voting and accepting an answer.